# Email notification to Case Queue members

Tags: case, queue

I have a Public Group which is part of of the queue. The public group has "grant access using hierarchies" enabled

Since Boss will have now have access to the case through the setting, will they also get emails whenever case is assigned to such queue ?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to replicate the behavior,  When 'Grant Access Using Hierarchies'is enabled, any records shared with users in this group are also shared with users higher in the role hierarchy.  However, it has nothing to do with email alerts.

Email alert will be sent only to members who are part of the public group.

Thanks